# How to assign a dynamic memory to a turtle about its movements to a set of patches/agents in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics, patch, agent-based-modeling, vehicle-routing

I have two breeds buyers and sellers. (1) Each buyer will look for the closest seller and go there.
(2) Buyer will do a transact and then look for next nearest seller and go there and so on. I tried with taking a attribute of the sellers "visited?", have the buyer have visited the seller?
Setup code:

```
breed [ buyers buyer ]
buyers-own [ target ]
patches-own [ visited? ]
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set visited? false ] 
  repeat 4 [
  ask one-of patches [   ;;used patches as sellers 
    set pcolor red  
    set visited? true 
  ]
]
  create-buyers 1 [
  set shape "person"  
  move-to one-of patches 
]

  reset-ticks
end
```

I have tried the 1st part of the problem as "go-to-nearest-seller" like this,

```
to go-to-nearest-seller
  ask buyers [
  let nearest-seller min-one-of patches with [visited?] [distance myself]
  move-to nearest-seller
  ]
end
```

But the part (2) is a bit tricky. I have done like this; "visit-all-seller"

```
to visit-all-seller

  while [any? patches with [visited?]] 
  [
    ask turtles [
    let nearest-seller min-one-of patches with [visited?] [distance myself]
    if nearest-seller!= nobody 
    [
      move-to nearest-seller
      ask nearest-seller [set visited? false] 
    ]
  ]
  ]
end
```

For a single buyer it is working fine. But when I am bringing more than one buyer, then this model is not working. Every customer is setting the attribute to true, so others are not visiting those sellers. Please guide me how to do it differently. Should I have to use dynamic lists or agent sets? Simple agentsets are not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This answer is still valid for Netlogo 6.3.0. As of Netlogo 6.4.0, an easier solution has presented itself using `who-are-not`.

---

Before I solve your issue, I have a few general suggestions.

I find it very confusing that you change `visited?` from true to false after they are visited. This should definitely be the other way around, otherwise you or someone else working on the code will eventually get confused and make an error.

Instead of `repeat 4 [ ask one-of patches [...] ]` you can also do `ask n-of 4 patches [...]` Your initial code also runs the risk of asking the same patch to change color twice, resulting in only 3 coloured patches instead of 4.

Now on to your problem:

You are correct in that you can't do it the same way anymore for multiple buyers. One option would be to make a separate `patches-own` variable for each buyer, but that can get clunky quite easily.
Instead, I suggest working with a `turtles-own` variable that stores all the patches that a turtle still wants to visit. I call it `destinations`. This is a patch-set and thus you can use it with the same primitives such as `min-one-of`.
That leaves the issue of removing a patch from this patch-set, which is actually quite annoying. Subsetting a patch-set can be done using primitives like `min-n-of`, `max-n-of`, `n-of` and `other`. Of these `other` is the only one that removes just one patch from the set. If we want to target a patch-set with `other`, it has to be called by a patch, but the patch itself can't freely access the destinations variable of the turtle. To circumvent this, I let the turtle create a local patch-set using `let`.

```
let new-destinations destinations
```

The patch can then remove itself from this set, and the turtle can finally use this set to get its new destinations

```
ask nearest-seller [ set new-destinations other new-destinations]
set destinations new-destinations
```

Altogether that gives:

```
breed [ buyers buyer ]
buyers-own [ target ]
turtles-own [ destinations ]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  ask n-of 4 patches [   ;;used patches as sellers 
    set pcolor red  
  ]
  
  create-buyers 3 [
    set shape "person"  
    move-to one-of patches 
    set destinations patches with [pcolor = red]
  ]
  
  reset-ticks
end

to go-to-nearest-seller
  ask buyers [
  let nearest-seller min-one-of destinations [distance myself]
  move-to nearest-seller
  ]
end

to visit-all-seller
  
  while [any? turtles with [any? destinations]] [
    
    ask turtles [
      let nearest-seller min-one-of destinations [distance myself]
      if nearest-seller != nobody 
      [
        move-to nearest-seller
        let new-destinations destinations
        ask nearest-seller [ set new-destinations other new-destinations]
        set destinations new-destinations
      ]
    ]
  ]
  
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, I guess you could use lists to store your destinations, that you then turn into a temporary patch-set when you need to do `min-one-of`. Lists are much easier to subset

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for such elaborate and conceptually sound answer. I am new to NetLogo mostly learning from NetLogo dictionary and online sources. Basics are still not clear about using agent sets, lists properly. You are absolutely correct about the `visited?` and `ask n-of 4 patches [...]`, I will keep in mind. I was aware that a turtle can access and change patch variable but did not know that a patch also can do the opposite. What are the circumstances that occurs? Can we provide me some learning sources for NetLogo?

Comment: @Jack The patch cannot access a turtle's variable. That is why I have this workaround where I let the turtle create a local variables (using `let`). The turtle then asks the patch to change this local variable, and finally the turtle uses the changed local variable to change it's own variable.

Answer (score 0):

Two weeks after this answer, Netlogo announced a new updated version ([Netlogo 6.4.0 beta](https://groups.google.com/g/netlogo-users/c/VP1k2fs17f0?pli=1))!
This version adds a primitive called `who-are-not` that seems to be specifically intended for subsetting agent-sets.

```
to visit-all-seller
  
  while [any? turtles with [any? destinations]] [
    
    ask turtles [
      let nearest-seller min-one-of destinations [distance myself]
      if nearest-seller != nobody 
      [
        move-to nearest-seller
        set destinations destinations who-are-not patch-here
      ]
    ]
  ]
  
end
```